# Time based filter out then get the Min(date) SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, dbeaver

With the below query I am getting Min(date) of the ID in 13 month period.
But I need to filter out the accounts with NO event in last 13 month, & then take the real Min(Date) of remaining accounts , not min(date) in last 13 months.

```
 select ID , event, min(Date) as Start_date
          from Table1
          where event is not null
          and date > cast(current_date - interval '13' month as timestamp)
          group by 1,2
```

Please advise!

Comment: Can you please add some example data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select ID , event, min(Date) as Start_date
          from Table1
          where not (event is null
          and date > current_date - interval '13 month')
          group by 1,2
```